# How to programmatically verify intermediate certificate signature with root public key?

Tags: c++, openssl

**Background**

I have the following chain:

1. Root certificate, self signed
2. Intermediate certificate, issued by Root
3. User certificate, issued by Intermediate

I am trying to verify signature of intermediate certificate using public key of issuer (Root). I am using the following code piece to implement this task:

```
int verify_cert_sig(X509 *issuer, X509 *cert){

    EVP_PKEY *public_key = X509_get_pubkey(issuer);

    if(public_key == NULL){
        _log->error("unable to get public key");
        return ERROR;
    }

    int result = X509_verify(cert, public_key);

    EVP_PKEY_free(public_key);

    if(result <= 0){
        return ERROR;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

int verify_sig(const std::string &issuer, const std::string &cert){

    X509 *issuer_x509 = load_cert("root.pem", X509_FILETYPE_PEM);
    if(issuer_x509 == NULL){
        _log->error("unable to load x509 cert: {}", issuer);
        return ERROR;
    }

    X509 *cert_x509 = load_cert("intermediate.pem", X509_FILETYPE_PEM);
    if(cert_x509 == NULL){
        _log->error("unable to load x509 cert: {}", cert);
        return ERROR;
    }

    auto rv = verify_cert_sig(issuer_x509, cert_x509);

    X509_free(issuer_x509);
    X509_free(cert_x509);

    if(rv <= 0){
        return ERROR;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**Issue**

For reasons unknown to me, the previous snippet will return error.

However, if I use openssl cli I can verify intermediate with root:

```
$:openssl verify -verbose -CAfile root.pem intermediate.pem
subroot.pem: OK
```

**Questions**

- What am I doing wrong? Did I miss something?
- How can I verify the signature of intermediate certificate using public key of issuer?

Comment: Your openssl code to check certs is fine.  So there is something incorrect with your certificate or certificate loading.  Are you sure you are checking the correct certificates with the correct issuer / issued.

Comment: @ShanePowell I am 100% sure that I am using the correct certificates as root and subroot. I just realized the problem: `verify_cert_sig` will return `ERROR` which is defined as `#define ERROR 0xFF`. However, in `verify_sig` function I am verifying `if (rv <= 0)` which will never be true as the return value from `verify_cert_sig` is positive. Sometimes I miss the crucial things like this :/